# compiler error c++ msys-1.0.dll windows

Tags: c++, windows-7, makefile, compiler-errors

I am trying to run simple program but get the following compiler error:
$./lab2
/directory here/lab2.exe: error while loading shared libraries: msys-1.0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

here is my makefile and code:

> ---
>
> ```
> # CS240 Lab2 Makefile
> ```
>
> all: lab2
>
> lab2: main.o tenstrings.o     g++ main.o
>   tenstrings.o -o lab2
>
> main.o: main.cpp      g++ -Wall -c
>   main.cpp -o main.o
>
> tenstrings.o: tenstrings.cpp  g++
>   -Wall -c tenstrings.cpp -o tenstrings.o
>
> ```
> tenstrings.h
> ```
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
#ifndef TENSTRNGS
#define TENSTRNGS

class TenStrings
{
public: 
    // Default Constructor
    TenStrings(); 
    TenStrings str[10];
};

#endif

    tenstrings.cpp 
--------------------------*/
#include "TenStrings.h"

using namespace std;

//Default Constructor
TenStrings::TenStrings()
{
private:

    str[0] = "String 1";
    str[1] = "String 2";
    str[2] = "String 3";
    str[3] = "String 4";
    str[4] = "String 5";
    str[5] = "String 6";
    str[6] = "String 7";
    str[7] = "String 8";
    str[8] = "String 9";
    str[9] = "String 10";

    std::cout << str[2] << std::endl;
}
;

    main.cpp 
--------------------------*/
#include "TenStrings.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    TenStrings varTen;


    return 0; 
}
```

---

I am trying to do part B of this lab: http://cs.binghamton.edu/~sgreene/cs240-2010f/labs/lab2.html
so if you can not only give me advice on the running exe error but also tell me if I am getting part B right as well. Thanks.

Comment: btw. how do you format so all your code is in stack overflow standards so its legible? when I paste my code in using the code tags, it still makes the code different font sizes and is hard to read.

Comment: @user593301: Step 1: Paste code in. Step 2: Select all code. Step 3: Click the "code" icon in the editor (it looks like a pair of braces). Alternately, just indent your code snippet by four spaces in your favorite text editor.

Comment: I'm amazed this compiles, to be honest - the definition of TenStrings appears to be recursive and I didn't think that was allowed.

Comment: what you mean its recursive? Its just an empty type no?

Comment: @user593301: No, it's not an empty type.  The compiler needs to reserve space for the TenStrings structure.  Since the TenStrings class contains a TenStrings class instance, each TenStrings class needs to allocate storage for ten more TenStrings objects.  Which is recursive and blows up (on visual studio x86, it reports that the object is larger than 2G and stops compiling).

Answer (score 0):

That's not a compiler error actually.  You're getting an error from your OS when you run the program saying that it can't find all the libraries it is linked to, namely the mingw runtime.

Mingw doesn't install those dll's in the system32 like some others.  You can solve the problem by making sure that the dll you're getting the error about is in your PATH.  One good place is to copy it (don't move it of course) into the directory containing your exe.

Answer (score 0):

The code as written doesn't compile.  The problem is that your TenStrings class contains an array TenStrings objects.  Since each TenStrings requires that the compiler provide storage for ten TenStrings objects, it can't compile.

Try replacing the "TenStrings str[10]" with "std::string str[10]" and see how that works.

Edit: If you have to use pointers to characters, then try "const char *str[10]".

Comment: Actually, the homework assignment that user593301 is working on doesn't allow use of std::string. The array needs to be an array of char pointers. (Yeah, I know...)

Comment: anyways. in part c of the lab what does he mean by "Allow the class user to set the 10 strings using regular assignment"? Does he mean that a user will input a string? or the class in the code will determine it? confused in so many parts